# Looking for Classical/Romantic Music that used a String Quartet/Quintet with a Lute/Guitar

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music, guitar, playlists, string-quartet

The title says it all,

Need Classical/Romantic Music that used a String Quartet/Quintet with a Lute/Guitar, Preferably the simpler ones (I understand "simple" here is subjective, What I mean is that if you know a good lot of pieces that have this arrangement suggest the simplest of them in terms of playing/complexity).

I found a few arrangements of stuff that weren't originally this arrangement, but am looking for those with this arrangement originally. I found a few concertos for Lute arranged for Guitar too, but I'm in need of a Quartet/Quintet arrangement, not a single instrument leading the section.

I would prefer single-movement works, or if not then works that are of short duration. I found an arrangement of String Quartet no. 8 of Haydn but it was a bit too large (18 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

The best known guitar quintets are the four written by [Luigi Boccherini](https://imslp.org/wiki/Category:Boccherini,_Luigi). There are several others [listed](https://imslp.org/wiki/Category:For_guitar,_2_violins,_viola,_cello) at the Petrucci Music Library.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this book](https://www.worldcat.org/title/handbook-of-guitar-and-lute-composers/oclc/176947036) helpful:

Annala, Hannu, and Heiki Mätlik. 2007. *Handbook of guitar and lute composers*. Pacific, MO: Mel Bay.

It appears to be available as an ebook, which would facilitate searching. A quick search via Google books turned up both Boccherini (as expected, based on PiedPiper's answer) and also a guitar with string quintet (and percussion) by [Abel Carlevaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_Carlevaro), *Fantasia Concertante*: "[Entrada](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mgt-Hzojpos)", "[Diálogo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gncbwOIQMVE)", "[Epilogo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1rEczPFu_g)". (The Carlevaro does not sound "simple" to me, by any definition.)

From the [publisher's website](https://www.melbay.com/Products/98524EB/handbook-of-guitar-and-lute-composers.aspx):

> In compiling this landmark sourcebook, Finnish guitarists Hannu Annala and Heiki Matlik consulted more than 70 music texts as well as dozens of composer resumes acquired from the musical information centers of several countries. During the writing process, which lasted for more than three years, they received additional information from many modern composers, including Leo Brouwer and Reginald Smith Brindle among others. In addition, several internationally renowned performing guitarists provided valuable